# Jenkins "Build a Visual Studio project using MSBuild" no version option

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I am setting up Jenkins for our project, but when I set up the "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild", there is no option for the MSbuild Version (Only shows Default) screen shot attached. Anyone knows how to point the MSBuild Version? I need some help.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [build .net application in Jenkins using MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227967/build-net-application-in-jenkins-using-msbuild)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"To use this plugin, specify the location directory of MSBuild.exe on Jenkin's configuration page" source: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSBuild+Plugin

You should be able to get to it from... localhost:8080/configure

Or... From the Jenkins home page click on "Manage Jenkins" and then click on "Configure System"

After you add the location of Msbuild you should see it available in your project configuration when you utilize the Msbuild plugin.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am using Jenkins 2.x. The global configurations need to be set in  Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration. And in Jenkins 2.x, if I choose default, it will automatically running msbuild.exe (which need to be  set in system variable)  :)